# How to parse the Array of dictionaries using swift Unbox

Tags: ios, unbox

I am using unboxing (https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox.git) for Object mapping in my Project I have a problem with this, I am unable to parse the data when it is comes as a Array from service. For example if the data is in the below form

```
[
    {
        "name": "Spotify",
        "id":"101"
    },
    {
        "name": "Netflix",
        "id":"102"
    }
]
```

Getting an exception from the Unboxer, can we map Array objects through Object mapper? Please help me...

Comment: What is the exception?  Please show your code.

Comment: possible to get invalid json format from server.check your real data once with online json converter http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question?

Comment: @lucasl Not yet, if you have any suggetions pls let me know

Comment: Can you share the code that leads to the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Unbox maps your JSON to structures or classes, therefore you have to have a struct/class that conforms to `Unboxable` protocol. For example:

```
struct Item: Unboxable {
    var id: String
    var name: String

    init(unboxer: Unboxer) throws {
        self.id = try unboxer.unbox(key: "id")
        self.name = try unboxer.unbox(key: "name")
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so (provided URL serves your JSON example):

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/o8b4t")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _, _ in
    if let data = data {
        if let items: [Item] = try? unbox(data: data) {
            print(items.count, items.first?.name)
            // Output: 2 Optional("Spotify")
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

As for raw dictionaries or arrays, IMO there's no point of using Unbox for that, just use `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:)`, like this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/o8b4t")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _, _ in
    if let data = data {
        if let parsed = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [[String: String]] {
            print(parsed.count, parsed.first?["name"])
            // Output: 2 Optional("Spotify")
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Note: In real world you'd prefer catching thrown exceptions (if any).